# How can I block the calendar prerender when I click a button?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, calendar, prerender

I create a time sheet with a calendar. Now I am using the event calendar pre-render. But the event runs on every click. I want to block this event from firing when I click a button. Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
If( ! IsPostBack)
{
  //Execute Your code
}
```

When you click button => He don't pass by `( ! IsPostBack)`